# Dividing an array into the greatest amount of parts with equal sums

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion

The array can hold negative numbers. I've written this code using recursion. First I'm summing the first `i` elements and then I'm checking for each such sum if the rest of the array (starting from `i + 1`) can be divided with this sum.

It works for some cases but not for others. I've noticed that it doesn't work if there's a prime somewhere.

It works if I sort the array in descending order beforehand but I don't understand why.

In this case the output is 2, while it should be 0.

```
#include <iostream>

const int N = 5;

int tab[N] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4};
// returns the number of partitions with a given sum (or 0 if it can't be partitioned)
int divisions(int tab[N], int p, int sum) {
    if (N < 2) return 0;
    if (p == N) {
        return 1;
    }
    int s_sum = tab[p++];
    while (s_sum != sum && p < N) {
        s_sum += tab[p++];
    }
    if (s_sum == sum) {
        return divisions(tab, p, sum) + 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

// creates all the possible sums and returns the greatest number of partitions where each partition sums up to some sum
int compareAllDivisions(int tab[N]) {
    int maxResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
            sum += tab[j];
        }
        int result = divisions(tab, i + 1, sum);
        if (maxResult < result) {
            maxResult = result;
        }
    }
    if (maxResult >= 2) {
        return maxResult;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << compareAllDivisions(tab) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, I hope the maxResult should be initialized to INT_MIN, as there may be negative numbers and sum may be less than 0.

Comment: @GorStepanyan I think you'll have to forgive me but I might have insufficiently described the code and the values returned by the functions. The `divisions` function returns the number of partitions, so it's never negative. It can be 0 (which is the minimal value) or greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of return value of `if (s_sum == sum)` part.

It should be changed like below

```cpp
if (s_sum == sum) {
    int ret = divisions(tab, p, sum);
    if(ret == 0) return 0;
    else return ret + 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Your return value of `divisions` is 0 when can't make and pos number when can make.
So, let's consider when 0 returns in there. It can't make at the back, but it will return pos number!